# hitTest inside a MC

Tags: actionscript-3

hey im trying to make a brick breaker game i really just started and im having a problem
right now i have two MC the ball and the brick both on stage inside the brick i have the code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkHit);

function checkHit (e:Event):void{
if(this.hitTestObject(Ball)){
    trace("HIT!");
}
```

}

the instances names are correct and ive tride to change the Ball to stage.Ball but i gey the error "Symbol '1120: Access of undefined property Ball. on the line of the hitTestObject.

why? can i fix this? tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is a Ball? this is a inheritance by DisplayObject?

Ball is should be instance value and you're custom Object.

```
var ball:Ball = new Ball();
addChild(ball);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkHit);
function checkHit(e:Event):void
{
    if(this.hitTestObject(ball))
    {
        trace("hit!");
    }
}
```

show a this site: [how to create Brick Breaker Game?](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-brick-breaker-game-in-as3-part-1/)

this site is a good for you.

Comment: the "Ball" is the instance name of the ball on the mainframe what im trying to do is to write the code for the hit test inside the bricks indtead of the main code and thats the error that i get